# Stemming with WordNet using JWNL - Unable to install dictionary

Tags: java, api, dictionary, filenotfoundexception, wordnet

I am trying to stem a string using WordNet with the JWNL API. When I try to load the dictionary it gives me a FileNotFoundException.

This is the code initializing the dictionary:

```
public static void Initializer(){
    try {
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("file_properties.xml"));
        dictionary = Dictionary.getInstance();
        morphPro = dictionary.getMorphologicalProcessor();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JWNLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:169)
    at Algorithms.Stemmer.Initializer(Stemmer.java:54)
    at Algorithms.Stemmer.WordStemmer(Stemmer.java:33)
    at Algorithms.Stemmer.StringStemmer(Stemmer.java:26)
    at GUI.ButtonListener.actionPerformed(ButtonListener.java:167)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.install(FileBackedDictionary.java:111)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:32)
```

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the path, but I can not find out exactly what is wrong, since I changed the file `properties.xml` to use `C:\WordNet\2.1\dict\` - so that should be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found out what was wrong. It was looking for the wrong files. I renamed the index.verb, index.adj etc. to verb.idx... This solved the problem and the program is now able to lookup the words in the dictionary.

Comment: file mapping is based on version of wordnet being used. and should be specified in initialization file.

Answer (score 1):

In `file_properties.xml` change the version number to the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem.
The error was:

```
gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at gate.wordnet.JWNLWordNetImpl.init(JWNLWordNetImpl.java:62)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:432)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:139)
    at WordNetApp.main(WordNetApp.java:45)
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:169)
    at gate.wordnet.JWNLWordNetImpl.init(JWNLWordNetImpl.java:57)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.install(FileBackedDictionary.java:111)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:32)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Could not create a file manager of type class net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:98)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:32)
    ... 7 more
Caused by:
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\WordNet\index.verb

```
(The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.openFile(PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.java:76)
        at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.AbstractDictionaryFile.open(AbstractDictionaryFile.java:58)
        at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalog.open(DictionaryCatalog.java:45)
        at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalogSet.open(DictionaryCatalogSet.java:34)
        at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.<init>(FileManagerImpl.java:71)
        at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:96)
        ... 8 more
```

So I found the problem. In that properties.xml I given wrong path as:

`<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:/Program Files/WordNet/"/>`

So I changed its path to the directory contain verb file :

`<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:/Program Files/WordNet/2.1/dict/"/>`

So my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly you need to change the data.adj etc. to the form of adj.dat
(that is of course if you are not willing to change the version number in the file_properties.xml)

Answer (score 0):

jwnl doesn't work with wordnet 2.1 version. So try with wordnet 2.0
Then it works properly.